# A Python tkinter Activity Planner (To-do List)

Tags: python, performance, design-patterns, tkinter, to-do-list

I have created a simple Activity Planner that allows adding tasks and associated sub-tasks. It is mainly based on the `Treeview` widget. This being my first GUI-based project, I would like to know:

- If this is a good design pattern
- If this could have been better broken down
- About any typical features to be added
- How it can be optimized in terms of performance and storage
- About the pros and cons in general
- About better practices

I plan to remove the "Change Theme" feature. It's just there to assist in picking the right theme from the `ttkthemes` module. This is exactly why I had to wrap all my content in a Frame that fills up the entire outer root container that doesn't inherit the theme.

Any thoughts and help would be highly appreciated!

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.messagebox as tkmb
import tkinter.font as tkfont
import tkinter.filedialog
import ttkthemes as ttkt
import sys
import pickle

class Activity:
    """
    Represents a single activity.

    Attributes:
        name(str): Activity Name
        iid(str): Activity ID, uniquely identifies the activity
        start(str): Start Time
        end(str): End Time
        parent()

    """
    def __init__(self, name, start, end, priority, parent=None):
        self.name = name
        self.iid = id(name)
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.parent = parent #parent iid
        self.checked = False
        self.priority = priority

    def has_parent(self):
        return True if self.parent is not None else False

   #TODO: 
    def has_completed(self):
        self.checked = True

    #TODO:
    def notify(self):
        pass 

    def __str__(self):
        return str((self.name, self.iid, self.start, self.end, self.parent, self.priority))

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()


class ActivityTreeviewHandler:
    """
    Handles the treeview to which the activity objects are added
    """
    def __init__(self, tree_label_frame, on_item_select_callback=None, *cols):
        self.activity_tree = ttk.Treeview(tree_label_frame, columns=list(cols))
        self.activity_tree.heading('#0', text="Name")

        self.activities = [] #Activity maintainer list for serialization and deserialization
        for col in cols:
            self.activity_tree.heading(col, text=col)

        self.activity_tree.bind('<<TreeviewSelect>>', on_item_select_callback)
        self.activity_tree.pack(padx=50, pady=50)


    def add_activity(self, activity):
        """ If activity has a parent, adds it a sub activity else adds at the top level. 

            The iid attribute of activity is used as the item id in the tree."""
        self.activities.append(activity)
        if activity.has_parent():
                self.activity_tree.insert(activity.parent, 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))
        else:            
                self.activity_tree.insert('', 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))


    def remove_activity(self, activity_iid):
        """ Removes an activity from the list and not from the treeview"""
        #Prepare list of activities to be removed
        removed_activites = [activity for activity in self.activities if activity.iid in activity_iid]
        #Remove them 1 by 1
        for activity in removed_activites:
            self.activities.remove(activity)


    def remove_selected_activity(self):
        """ Removes the currently selected activity from the treeview and then calls remove_activity()"""
        sel = self.activity_tree.selection()
        self.activity_tree.delete(sel)
        self.remove_activity(sel)

    def save_state(self):
        """ Serializer; writes all activites in the current treeview to a file using pickle 
            and returns the destination file name.  Returns an empty string if fails.

            Return: 
                str (Returns the destination file name) 
          """
        try:
            with open(tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename( title="Enter File Name"), 'wb') as dest_file:
                #Serialize
                pickle.dump(self.activities, dest_file, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                return dest_file.name
        except Exception as e:
            tkmb.showerror("Failed", "Couldn't save list")
            return


    def clear_treeview(self):
        """ Empties the treeview """
        self.activity_tree.delete(*self.activity_tree.get_children())

    #Loads a list state from file after clearing the tree
    def load_state(self):
        """ Deserializer: Clears the tree, asks the user to open a saved file, and adds the activities to the tree
            and returns the file name. Returns an empty string if fails.

            Return: 
                str (Returns the destination file name) 
         """
        try:
             self.clear_treeview()
             with open(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename( title="Select File"), 'rb') as dest_file:
                 #Deserialize
                 self.activities = pickle.load(dest_file)

                 for activity in self.activities:
                     if activity.has_parent():
                        self.activity_tree.insert(activity.parent, 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))
                     else:            
                        self.activity_tree.insert('', 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))

                 return dest_file.name

        except Exception as e:
            tkmb.showerror("Failed", "Couldn't load list")
            return ""

class InputWindow:
    """ Represents the input window that 
        * Takes in the details of a new activity
        * Constructs an activity object from the details
        * Passes the constructed object to the ActivityTreeviewHandler object's add_activity()

         """
    def __init__(self, w_title, treeview_handler: ActivityTreeviewHandler, has_parent=False):
        #Create Toplevel
        self.container = tk.Toplevel()
        self.container.title(w_title)
        self.has_parent = has_parent
        self.adder_pane = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        self.adder_pane.pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH, ipadx=50, ipady=100)

        self.treeview_handler = treeview_handler
        #Create input fields
        self.activity_input = {}
        self.activity_input['name'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="Activity name:")
        self.activity_input['start'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="From :")
        self.activity_input['end'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="To :")
        self.activity_input['priority'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="Priority:")

        #Add to parent container
        self.activity_input['name'][1].grid(row=0, column=0, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['name'][0].grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['start'][1].grid(row=1, column=0, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['start'][0].grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['end'][1].grid(row=2, column=0, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['end'][0].grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['priority'][1].grid(row=3, column=0, pady=5)
        self.activity_input['priority'][0].grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5)

        ttk.Button(self.adder_pane, text="Add", command=self.construct_activity_from_input).grid(row=4,column=1)
        self.container.mainloop()


    def construct_activity_from_input(self):
        for field in self.activity_input:
                    if self.activity_input[field][0].get() == "":
                        tkmb.showerror("Empty field "+field, "Please enter a valid "+field)
                        return
        activity = Activity(
                self.activity_input['name'][0].get(),
                self.activity_input['start'][0].get(),
                self.activity_input['end'][0].get(),
                self.activity_input['priority'][0].get(),
                self.treeview_handler.activity_tree.selection()[0] if self.has_parent else None
            )
        self.treeview_handler.add_activity(activity)
        self.container.destroy()





class App:       
    """ The main Activity Planner App

        Attributes
        themes(list) - helps implementing change_theme()
        saved(bool) - monitors save state 
    """
    def __init__(self):

        self.container = ttkt.ThemedTk()
        self.master = ttk.Frame(self.container)
        self.master.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.themes = self.container.get_themes()

        self.tree_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="Your Activities")
        self.button_label_frame = ttk.LabelFrame(self.master, text="Modify")

        self.treeview_handler = ActivityTreeviewHandler(self.tree_label_frame, self.on_select, 'From', 'To', 'Priority') 

        self.add_button =  ttk.Button(self.button_label_frame, text="Add Activity...", command=self.on_add_activity)
        self.add_button.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, pady=10)

        self.remove_button = ttk.Button(self.button_label_frame, text="Delete Activity", state='disabled', command=self.on_delete_activity)
        self.remove_button.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, pady=10)

        self.add_sub_button = ttk.Button(self.button_label_frame, text="Add Sub Activity...", state='disabled', command=self.on_add_sub_activity)
        self.add_sub_button.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER, pady=10)
        self.theme_changer = self.change_theme()
        ttk.Button(self.button_label_frame, text="Change Theme", command= lambda: next(self.theme_changer)).pack(pady=10,  anchor=tk.CENTER)



        self.tree_label_frame.pack(padx=50, pady=25)
        self.button_label_frame.pack(padx=50, pady=25, fill=tk.X, expand=True)
        self.container.wm_state('zoomed')


        self.saved = True

        #Menu
        self.menubar = tk.Menu(self.container)

        self.menus = {}

        self.menus['file'] = tk.Menu(self.menubar, tearoff=0)
        self.menus['file'].add_command(label="New", command=self.new_instance)
        self.menus['file'].add_command(label="New Child Window", command=self.new_child_instance)
        self.menus['file'].add_separator()

        self.menus['file'].add_command(label="Save...", command=self.on_save)
        self.menus['file'].add_command(label="Load...", command=self.on_load)
        self.menus['file'].add_separator()

        self.menus['file'].add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit)

        self.menus['edit'] = tk.Menu(self.menubar)
        self.menus['edit'].add_command(label="Add Activity", command=self.on_add_activity)
        self.menus['edit'].add_command(label="Add Sub Activity", command=self.on_add_sub_activity)
        self.menus['edit'].add_command(label="Delete Activity", command=self.on_delete_activity )


        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=self.menus['file'])
        self.menubar.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=self.menus['edit'])                                       
        self.container.config(menu=self.menubar)
        self.container.title("Activity Planner")
        self.container.mainloop()


    def change_theme(self):
    """ Cycles through the available themes provided by ttkthemes"""
        while True:
            for thm in self.themes:
                self.container.set_theme(thm)
                yield


    def on_add_activity(self):
        InputWindow("Add a New Activity", self.treeview_handler)
        self.saved = False

    def on_add_sub_activity(self):
        InputWindow("Add a New Sub Activity", self.treeview_handler, has_parent=True)
        self.saved = False

    def on_delete_activity(self):
        self.treeview_handler.remove_selected_activity()
        self.saved = False
        self.add_sub_button['state'] = 'disabled'
        self.remove_button['state'] = 'disabled'

    def on_select(self, event):
         self.add_sub_button['state'] = 'normal'
         self.remove_button['state'] = 'normal'

    def quit(self):
        self.ask_save_state()
        self.container.destroy()
        sys.exit(0)

    def new_instance(self):
        self.ask_save_state()
        self.container.destroy()
        App()

    def new_child_instance(self):
        App()

    def ask_save_state(self):
        if not self.saved:
            if(tkmb.askyesno("Save List", "Do you want to save the list?")):
                self.on_save()

    def on_save(self):
        name = self.treeview_handler.save_state()
        self.container.title(name+ " - Activity Planner")
        self.saved = True

    def on_load(self):
        self.ask_save_state()
        name = self.treeview_handler.load_state()
        self.container.title(name+ " - Activity Planner")

App()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Type hints

```
"""
    Attributes:
        name(str): Activity Name
        iid(str): Activity ID, uniquely identifies the activity
        start(str): Start Time
        end(str): End Time
        parent()
"""
```

It's nice that you've documented these types, but it would be better to tell Python (or at least your IDE) about them:

```
def __init__(self, name: str, start: datetime, end: datetime, ...):
   self.name: str = name
   self.start: datetime = start
   ...
```

Note that if a variable is a time, it should actually be represented with a time type and not a string.

### Boolean expressions

```
return True if self.parent is not None else False
```

should be

```
return self.parent is not None
```

### Todo methods

Rather than `pass`, you should `raise NotImplementedError()`.

### `__str__`

Rather than string-izing a tuple like this:

```
    return str((self.name, self.iid, self.start, self.end, self.parent, self.priority))
```

you should probably be more deliberate and format a string, such as

```
return f'{self.name}: iid={self.iid} time={self.start}-{self.end}'
```

### Dynamic args

```
    if activity.has_parent():
            self.activity_tree.insert(activity.parent, 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))
    else:            
            self.activity_tree.insert('', 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))
```

can be

```
parent = activity.parent if activity.has_parent() else ''
self.activity_tree.insert(parent, 'end', activity.iid, text=activity.name, values=(activity.start, activity.end, activity.priority))
```

### Dictionary literals

```
    self.activity_input = {}
    self.activity_input['name'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="Activity name:")
    self.activity_input['start'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="From :")
    self.activity_input['end'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="To :")
    self.activity_input['priority'] = ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="Priority:")
```

can be

```
self.activity_input = {
    'name': (ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="Activity name:")),
    'start': (ttk.Entry(self.adder_pane), ttk.Label(self.adder_pane, text="From :")),
    ...
}
```